# brackets not included in the obtained json

Tags: json, ajax, servlets, highcharts

I have the following code on a Servlet

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        data.put( "x", "[[0, 29.9],[1, 71.5],[3, 106.4]]" );
        data.put( "y", "[[0.5, 28],[1.5, 60],[3, 100]]" );
        data.put("z","[[0.2, 20],[1.5, 40],[3, 120]]");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.putAll( data );
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().println(json);
```

and in the page I try to read each value, like

```
 $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/HEC/someservlet", function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(key, val) {
           console.log(key+' '+ val);
         });
     });
```

the problem is that eacch value printed at the console has the [ ] removed

> x 0,29.9,1,71.5,3,106.4
>
> y 0.5,28,1.5,60,3,100
>
> z 0.2,20,1.5,40,3,120

I was expecting to see this

> x [[0,29.9],[1,71.5],[3,106.4]]
>
> y [[0.5,28],[1.5,60],[3,100]]
>
> z [[0.2,20],[1.5,40],[3,120]]

but this did not happen!
Any idea why are the brackets removed and what can be done to have them back?

Thank you,

Sorin

Comment: `[ [ 1 ,2 ] ]` in json terms is of type `Array[Array]` not `Array[String]`

Answer (score 1):

Problem:

You create JSON from the `data` Map:

```
 data.put( "x", "[[0, 29.9],[1, 71.5],[3, 106.4]]" );
 data.put( "y", "[[0.5, 28],[1.5, 60],[3, 100]]" );
 data.put("z","[[0.2, 20],[1.5, 40],[3, 120]]");
```

This results in a JSON string which will look something like:

```
{
    "x": [[0, 29.9],[1, 71.5],[3, 106.4]],
    "y": [[0.5, 28],[1.5, 60],[3, 100]],
    "z": [[0.2, 20],[1.5, 40],[3, 120]]
}
```

Now in JavaScript terms, when the browser sees this result, it will interpret it as an object with keys, `x,y,z` and each key having an array of arrays as its value. This is why you don't get the `[ ]` to show up in the console, it's because the `[ ]` were to indicate an array in JSON and were no longer needed after the value had been interpreted. If you want to enforce a string try using:

```
 data.put( "x", "\"[[0, 29.9],[1, 71.5],[3, 106.4]]\"" );
 data.put( "y", "\"[[0.5, 28],[1.5, 60],[3, 100]]\"" );
 data.put("z","\"[[0.2, 20],[1.5, 40],[3, 120]]\"");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, excellent answer and maybe was a silly question from me, as a beginner in JSON and AJAX...